# Можно ли выполнить require() из одного WP сайта в другом, находящемся в поддомене?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, оптимизация-сайтов

Заголовок, возможно, написан несколько некорректно, поэтому попробую обрисовать проблему в целом.

По причинам? от меня не зависящим, мне достался сайт на WP с еще одним WP по адресу /blog/ из с непонятым(возможно кастомным) японским CMS по адресу /voice.php. Общий шаблон сайта есть и должен быть один, с единой навигацией и footer'ом.

Сами навигация и footer написаны и лежат в теме главного WP вызываются через require('...'); и это нельзя менять.

Сейчас навигация и footer в /voice.php и /blog/ написаны на чистом HTML и при любом изменении своих php файлов в главном WP будут отличатся.

Можно ли прописать вызов этих require('...'); из главной темы в сами /voice.php и /blog/?

Comment: Вопрос том, что в навигации и футере. Если чистый php - должно работать. Если присутствуют обращения к функциям WordPress, то без инициализации главного сайта не обойтись. Попробуйте сделать инициалиацию через require('/путь/wp-load.php');, а потом делать require навигации и футера.

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но должно работать:

```
<?php
require_once('../../../../wp-config.php');
require_once('../../../../wp-includes/wp-db.php');
?>
```

Путь для файлов, соответственно, нужно указать свой.

Comment: А лучше используйте абсолютный путь чтобы с точками не запутаться! )